# VBA find, copy and paste loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with two columns "key" and "comp"

another table with the "Return" column

In the "Return" column, I enter the value of the second line manually, and I would like it to look for the "key" reference from this value and copy the "comp" to the next empty line, repeating this process until no more values are found.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY1q8.png)

I tried to use lookup with vba but I was not successful with the code

Comment: Would be nice if you'd share your coding effords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, according to your explanation - that's all you need. Just update worksheet name and cells:

```
Sub foo()
Dim target As Range, c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set target = sht.Cells(2, 5)

Dim srcRange As Range

Set srcRange = Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each c In srcRange
    If c.Value = target.Value Then
        target.Offset(1, 0).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set target = target.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

This code assumes column "Key" as column "A", column "Comp" as column "B" and column "Return" as column "E".